# How can I stream video captured from my webcam to wowza media server?

Tags: html, video-streaming, video-capture, wowza

I have captured the stream object returned by HTML5 camera object to wowza server which can be further streamed to other devices. How can I do that.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a software encoder that is capturing your webcam/mic and encoding it into one of these streaming protocols (RTMP, RTSP, MPEG-TS), then you should be able to just publish your stream to your Wowza server.

1. Make sure that your Wowza services are running.
2. If it's a default installation, it should already be installed with an application called "live".
3. If you are sending your live stream through RTMP, then you only need to publish it to your Wowza server by sending it to the following URL: rtmp://<wowzaServerIP>:1935/live/<streamName> where <wowzaServerIP> refers to your Wowza server's IP address, and <streamName> is any string.
4. If you are sending your live stream through RTSP, just change the protocol accordingly.
5. To playback the stream, you can use VLC or any web player (such as JWPlayer, TheOPlayer, or Flowplayer), and playback the stream using the same URL. Do note that some players do not support all protocols/formats. VLC is your best bet for playing back streams in a test environment.